# Why does a sorted parquet file have a larger size than a non-sorted one?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataframe created as follows :

```
expanded_1 = pd.DataFrame({"Point": [random.choice(points) for x in range(30000000)], 
                     "Price": [random.choice(prices) for x in range(30000000)]
                    })
```

that i stored as a parquet file, the size of this on disk is 90.2 MB.

Post researching on how compression is being done with parquet, i sorted the values by Point so that similar data can is kept together with the understanding that this will allow the default parquet compression technique to be more efficient. However the results I saw were quite opposite. On running the following :

```
expanded_1.sort_values(by=['Point']).to_parquet('/expanded_1_sorted.parquet')
```

the resulting file was 211 MB in size.

What is causing the size increase ?

Comment: What's the output of printing both?

Comment: By any chance can you share what `points` and `prices` are?  You can generally find more information about how a parquet file is encoded by inspecting the return of pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata.  If you inspect the metadata of both files does that reveal anything interesting?

Comment: @Pace I got similar results with `points = prices = range(1000)`. I think it's the scrambled index, and `reset_index(drop=True)` seems to fix it. (But I don't really know what I'm doing.)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode  A scrambled index makes perfect sense.  Arrow will detect a simple linear index and store it is as metadata instead of an actual column.  In the event the index is scrambled it will be forced to save an actual column and it will use int64.  Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the scrambled index, and `reset_index(drop=True)` seems to fix it. Instead of much bigger it became much smaller (half the unsorted original) when I tested with `points = prices = range(1000)`.

Or as @0x26res points out, `.sort_values(by=['Point'], ignore_index=True)` is more efficient. No need to fix what you don't break. Result is the same.

Comment: It's more efficient to call `.sort_values(by=['Point'], ignore_index=True)`, rather than later call `reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Proves what I said earlier, that I don't really know what I'm doing :-). Thanks, added.