# Why does parquet size increase when using partitionBy on the write function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

When I used the

```
df.partitionBy('column1', 'column2')
```

when writing a PySpark dataframe to s3 in parquet format, , my parquet (~26 million rows, ~2000 columns size went up from 50 GB to about 150 GB. Why does partitioning increase file size, and is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: can you try dropping the index when partitioning ? i imagine the index is getting scrambled and now to store that we have more data being added

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399523/why-does-a-sorted-parquet-file-have-a-larger-size-than-a-non-sorted-one

Comment: @AbhishekMalik it looks like reset_index only applies to pandas dataframes, not pyspark dataframes. FYi I can't use pandas dataframes in my project as it would result in a memoryerror

Comment: How many partitions/files are there? Each file as to store the meta data (schema etc) which creates an overhead. If your partitions are too small then this can be significant.